# Unisex bathroom synchronization

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I have come up with the following solution for the unisex bathroom synchronization.

The problem has the following constraints:

- There is a shared bathroom which has a limited capacity.
- Males and females cannot use the bathroom at the same time
- An individual will spend arbitrary some time using the bathroom
- An individual does not like to wait to use the bathroom (minimize waiting time)
- The solution should not be biased to males or females.

See [link](http://www.credmond.net/projects/unisex-bathroom-problem/) for a detailed description of the problem.

Does the below mentioned solution satisfy all the problem constraints?

**Pseudo code**

```
int female_cnt = 0;
mutex female_cnt_mutex;

int male_cnt = 0;
mutex male_cnt_mutex;

mutex female_mutex;
mutex male_mutex;

semaphore restroom = N;

female()
{
    lock(female_mutex)
    unlock(female_mutex)

    lock(female_cnt_mutex)

    female_cnt++;
    if (female_cnt == 1)
        lock(male_mutex)

    unlock(female_cnt_mutex)

    wait(restroom)

    do_stuff();

    signal(restroom)

    lock(female_cnt_mutex)

    female_cnt--;
    if (female_cnt == 0)
        unlock(male_mutex)

    unlock(female_cnt_mutex)
}

male()
{
    lock(male_mutex)
    unlock(male_mutex)

    lock(male_cnt_mutex)

    male_cnt++;
    if (male_cnt == 1)
        lock(female_mutex)

    unlock(male_cnt_mutex)

    wait(restroom)

    do_stuff();

    signal(restroom)

    lock(male_cnt_mutex)

    male_cnt--;
    if (male_cnt == 0)
        unlock(female_mutex)

    unlock(male_cnt_mutex)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty critical section

```
    lock( female_mutex )
    unlock( female_mutex )
```

at the beginning of `female` function **doesn't prevent male() and female() to be executed concurrently**.

If `female()` pass this critical section before `male()` execute code after its empty critical section, nothing prevents both these functions to proceed up to `wait( restroom )`. Such a way they violate 2nd requirement.